# How to change manufacture data when advertise as beacon?

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon

Manufacture data of apple is {0x00, 0x4c}, Is there anyway to change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On iOS there is no way to advertise a Bluetooth LE manufacturer advertisement (the type used for iBeacon) without using an operating-system supplied template for iBeacon that fixes the format and forces the manufacturer code to Apple's 0x004c.  So the short answer is no.

Other platforms such as Android there is no such restriction and you can vary the advertisement format and manufacturer code all you want.

Even if you do change the manufacturer code on a transmitter, it will break iOS's ability to detect the beacon transmission, because the receiver is fixed time look for advertisements with 0x004c.